# How to redirect one page to a different URL than the rest of the HTTP redirect IIS8

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, windows-server-2012, iis-8

First off, apologies for not knowing the nomenclature for what I'm looking for, I'm not typically a Windows web admin.

I have a SharePoint website which contains several subsites. We also have several alternate URLs that point to specific pages, and some of those alternate URLs have friendly URLs which also redirect to other specific pages. We're in the process of migrating from a SharePoint 2007 site to this one, and in the process, I'm trying to remove our reliance on our registrar for handling some of this redirection, because it is apparently not a free service.

Currently our registrar does the following redirects:

1. http://alias1.tld/* redirects to http://subsite1.ca/page1
2. http://alias1.tld/friendly redirects to http://subsite1.ca/page2
3. http://alias2.tld/ redirects to http://subsite1.ca/page3

I know I can accomplish the first and second by setting the sites up in IIS, and using the HTTP Redirect function, but I'm not sure how I can do the second one. In Apache this would be easy, but I'm not sure what I'm looking for here.

Is this something that should be handled within SharePoint, and have that take care of redirecting alias1.tld/friendly to the specific page, or is this something I need to setup in IIS? Is this what URL rewrite is for, or is there a different IIS way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is the best way to do it, but I got things working how I wanted them. Here's what I ended up doing:

1. *Create a new subsite* on *subsite1* to give me the URL *subsite1.ca/subsubsite*
2. Create a redirect from *alias1.tld* to *subsite1.ca/subsite*
3. *Create 2 pages* for the new subsite. One for the default page and one to use to redirect to page2. Both pages are redirects, *Default* points to *Page1*, the *second* points to *Page2*.
4. Set the subsite to use **Managed Navigation** for *global* and *current* through *Site Settings > Navigation*, and created a default term set by selecting the new subsite in the list and then clicking *Create Term Set*, then clicking *OK*.
5. Then created a *term store* for the one page that needs to be handled differently by going to *Site Settings > Term Store Management*. Click on the Term Set created in the last step, then select *New Term*. On the *Term-Driven Pages* tab, create the friendly URL and then select the target page, which is the redirect page created in step 3, then click Save.